# Executing dynamically generated Jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dynamic

Can any body please tell me the difference between

1. `$(".level3_td[data-levelid=" + 01 + "]")` and
2. `$(".level3_td[data-levelid=01]")`

I am dynamically generating `$(".level3_td[data-levelid=" + 01 + "]")` but it doesn't seem to find the item that I am trying to find. Then I tried to paste it in the console and found that it wasn't able to find the DOM object. After that I tried the 2nd one by hard coding  `$(".level3_td[data-levelid=01]")` and it worked.

Can anybody please tell me what's the difference between both of these and how may I get the first one to work?

Comment: Surely `01` will result in `levelid=1`. Leading zeros are not a component of an integral number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `01` is getting converted into a `1`, dropping the `0`. You'll need to tell Javascript that you want to treat the `01` as a string by wrapping it in quotes. Something like:

```
$(".level3_td[data-levelid=" + "01" + "]")
```

So in reality, your code is attempting to access `$(".level3_td[data-levelid=1]")` which most likely does not exist.

Comment: Thanks but in case when 01 is being generated by a variable, how may I get this to work?

Comment: @KamranAhmed There's no built in functionality, to the best of my knowledge, for zero padding out an integer like that. You're going to have to roll your own: http://jsfiddle.net/qQUfX/